# Netflix Desktop Has Stopped Working - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: netflix

Appreciate any assistance anyone can provide! :)

Netflix desktop has stopped working.  It's been working for months, however, stopped working today.  It's asking me to install Silverlight.  Was installed previously using the following terminal commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipelight-multi

sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight

sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

Comment: Just so you know, you can already use Netflix with Google chrome without the need of running a plugin thru wine, as long as your system is updated.

Comment: There is no longer any need to use Netflix Desktop. Perhaps you don't know this, but Netflix will work on Ubuntu 14.04 as long as you use Google Chrome and have your system up to date. No fancy user-agent hacking is required anymore. I encourage you to stop using Netflix Desktop and Pipelight and start using this fully-native way of watching Netflix.